# How to use a single puppet erb template to create two different files with different contents

Tags: puppet

I'm trying to use a single template file to create the Solaris 11 /etc/hosts.deny and /etc/hosts.allow files, with the hiera data in data/Solaris.json.

How can I have the hosts.deny file contain only "ALL: ALL", while the hosts.allow contain the "ALL: ALL" **and** the variable content from the Solaris.json file?

It should be noted that my org is using Puppet 5.5 Open Source, with ruby templates and json instead of yaml.

Here's the manifest.

```
class etc::solaris_hosts_files (
  Array[String] $entry,
) {
  file { 'hosts.allow': # Creates /etc/hosts.allow using template.
    ensure  => 'present',
    content => template('etc/solaris_hosts_template.erb'),
    owner   => 'root',
    group   => 'other',
    path    => '/etc/hosts.allow',
    mode    => '0444',
  }

  file { 'hosts.deny': # Creates /etc/hosts.deny using template.
    ensure  => 'present',
    content => template('etc/solaris_hosts_template.erb'),
    owner   => 'root',
    group   => 'other',
    path    => '/etc/hosts.deny',
    mode    => '0444',
  }
}
```

Here is the template file.

```
ALL: ALL
<% unless $etc::solaris_hosts_files::hosts.allow -%>
<%= @entry.join(' ') %>
```

Here is the data/Solaris.json variable info.

```
"etc::solaris_hosts_files::entry": [
        "<some_net>:<some_mask>",
        "<some_net>:<some_mask>  #<some_hostname>" ],
```

In the interest of being thorough, yes, the @entry variable is included in data/common.json. We assign the value in Solaris.json.

```
"etc::solaris_hosts_files::entry": "",
```

I am a noob puppeteer. Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you!!

Comment: Can you please show the expected versus actual rendered content?

Comment: Expected results would be:

hosts.deny file:
`ALL: ALL`

hosts.allow file:
```
ALL: ALL
<some_ip>:<some_mask>
<some_ip>:<some_mask>
...
```

PS - first time using Stack overflow. Forgive the formatting mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Posting an answer to Matt Schuchard's question.

hosts.deny

`ALL: ALL`

hosts.allow:

```
ALL: ALL
<ip>:<mask>
<ip>:<mask>
```

The ip:mask comes from the hiera data.

The rendered result is an error:

```
Info: Retrieving locales
Info: Loading facts
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: No content type in http response; cannot parse
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```